# Getting the JSON file when triggering AJAX

Tags: ajax, json, web-crawler

I'm writing a crawler to get the content from a website which uses AJAX.
There is a "show more" button at the bottom of the page, and my origin approach is to use Selenium.PhantomJS to pretend a web browser but it works in some website and some don't.

I'm wondering if there is some way i can directly get the underly JSON file of the AJAX action. Please give me some details, thanks.

By the way, I'm using Python.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is less of a python than a scraping problem in general (and I understand you meant "scraping" instead of "crawling" as a scraper reads/parses/processes one page whereas a crawler processes multiple pages and they're relation to each other).

You can get the JSON file immediately given you know it's URL. If you don't (for example because the URL changes from time to time), you might need to search through javascript files on the page manually to find out how the URL is generated.

Once you know the JSON file's URL, it's quite simple. As you already seem to know how to get the HTML of the "main" page, you can use your existing code to get the JSON file.

I'm not familiar with PhantomJS, but I reckon it's easier to get the JSON file immediately instead of simulating an AJAX request (if that's even possible with Phantom).